# Is this answer an answer or a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers

While I was reviewing some late answers, I flagged this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669274/5277820) as `Not an answer', because:

- the answer comments (without a link) on another (accepted) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16342490/5277820),
- the answer is for Crystal report 2008, but OP ask for Crystal Reports XI Release 2 and tagged as [crystal-reports-xi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crystal-reports-xi)

Later I reviewed a second answer, which also related to another answer and I got unconfident. So my question is: Should I flag answers releated to another answer?

I read [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer) already, but I still don't know, if I should flag this particular answer.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [When to flag as answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: The answer to "_Should I flag answers releated to another answer?_" is no.  They are answers by definition (you admitted it as much yourself).  They are incorrect and should be downvoted instead.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly speaking, a NAA flag isn't really appropriate here, as this *does* attempt to be an answer to the question. There are, however, three glaring problems that must be dealt with:

1. It refers to some other answer, but neither gives credit to the person who provided that answer nor links to it so people have a hope of figuring out what the heck he's talking about.

   This problem can be fixed with a simple edit, as [I've already done](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35669274/revisions).
2. Aside from adding that Ryan's solution does not work on version 2008 of the software, this answer provides no *additional* information that Ryan's answer lacks. In other words, while evaluated independently (as a moderator would from the NAA queue), it would seem to be an answer, it is not a *useful* answer because it simply rehashes the contents of an answer that was posted some 3 years ago.

   The "this does not work on Crystal Reports 2008; you must upgrade to a newer version" is arguably useful information, but it alone is insufficient to justify an answer. It is a clarification to an existing answer, and should therefore have been posted as a comment. You cannot expect a moderator to figure this out simply by flagging it as NAA. You'd need to raise a custom flag, explain the situation, and request that they convert it to a comment.
3. The morsel of additional information that this answer does provide about Ryan's solution not working on Crystal Reports 2008 is arguably irrelevant, since the asker says he's using Crystal Reports XI Release 2, both in the body of the question and via the use of a version-specific tag.

   I would warn caution with this, though, since Stack Overflow is not a help desk. The Q&A is intended to be useful to everyone who comes across it, not just the asker. As such, it can be quite useful to point out the limitations of a solution, even if those limitations do not apply to the specific individual who first asked the question.

   Either way, this is up to you to decide if it is a useful answer and how you should respond. If you dislike it and think the answer is not useful, then you can award it a downvote. This is not an issue that requires moderator intervention.